# How do I create nested hashmaps of mixed types?

Tags: java, tree, hashmap, mustache

I'm new to Java and I have a problem that I can't figure out how to solve.
I have an existing HashMap that looks like this:

```
[
{
    linkText=Link Text, 
    link=http://www.someurl.com, 
    heading=Asia}, 
{
    linkText=Link Text, 
    link=http://www.someurl.com, 
    heading=Asia
}
{
    linkText=Link Text, 
    link=http://www.someurl.com, 
    heading=Europe
}
{
    linkText=Link Text, 
    link=http://www.someurl.com, 
    heading=Africa
}
]
```

I need to transform this HashMap into something that will allow me to do this in Mustache:

```
<ul>
{{#linkGroups}}
<li>{{heading}}
  <ul>
    {{#links}}
    <li><a href="{{link}}">{{linkText}}</a></li>
    {{/links}}
  </ul>
</li>
{{/linkGroups}}
</ul>
```

I don't think I have enough knowledge on existing data types that allow nesting of this nature. I've tried with HashMap, Set, and Tree but it's not coming up. I *think* whatever type I end up using needs to let me do something like this:

```
[
    {
        heading=Asia,
        links= {
            {
                linkText=Link Text,
                link=http://www.someurl.com
            }
            {
                linkText=Link Text,
                link=http://www.someurl.com
            }
        }
    }
    {
        heading=Europe,
        links= {
            {
                linkText=Link Text,
                link=http://www.someurl.com
            }
            {
                linkText=Link Text,
                link=http://www.someurl.com
            }
        }
    }
]
```

But I could be wrong and over complicating the object.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have a map that combines three elements in each entry? Usually map is key=value structure, is not it?

Comment: You're right, good observation. The object is actually a List, created like this: `List<HashMap<String, String>> linksList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();`

Answer (score 2):

Supposing your create a class like that:

```
class Link
{
    public String text;
    public String url;
}
```

The structure you are describing could made with:

```
HashMap<String, List<Link>>
```

or using guava library:

```
ListMultimap<String, Link>
```